# Oracle application server logging

Tags: oracle, logging, webserver

Can somebody tell me where I can set the path for the  application log files which are on the Oracle application server because I can't find nothing in the web. 
For an example I have a web app which I have been deployed on the server and this one have redirect errors output log and my question is from where the file path of the log is set?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're looking for, but sounds like you need the **OPMN** configurations.
These can be found usually (and depends on your version) in 'ORACLE_HOME/opmn/conf/'.
The file you probably want is 'opmn.xml'

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13597_05/core.904/b12057/intro.htm#i1017874) is a link for some documentation

Comment: i'm looking the conf file where i set tha path to the log files for the application which are deployed on the oracle application server?